# u-boot: cannot boot linux kernel despite kernel being less than maximum BOOTM_LEN

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mips, u-boot

I have a MIPS system (VSC7427) with u-boot and I am trying to boot a more recent kernel than the kernel provided by the vendor in their GPL release (which [boots just fine](https://gist.github.com/halmartin/36a7ca3308be9a637abab6a17376593e)).

The kernel FIT image appears to be sane, and judging by the output I think it should be bootable:

```
U-Boot 2019.10 (Mar 28 2021 - 20:41:55 +0000)

MSCC VCore-III MIPS 24Kec
Model: Cisco Meraki MS220-8P
DRAM:  128 MiB
Loading Environment from SPI Flash... SF: Detected mx25l12805d with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 16 MiB
OK
In:    serial@10100000
Out:   serial@10100000
Err:   serial@10100000
Net:   
Warning: switch@1010000 (eth0) using random MAC address - b2:6b:53:af:2d:a0
eth0: switch@1010000
luton # dhcp
(snipped)
luton # tftp vmlinux.gz.itb
Using switch@1010000 device
TFTP from server 192.168.1.60; our IP address is 192.168.1.154
Filename 'vmlinux.gz.itb'.
Load address: 0x80100000
Loading: #################################################################
(snipped)
done
Bytes transferred = 5172244 (4eec14 hex)
luton # iminfo 0x80100000

## Checking Image at 80100000 ...
   FIT image found
   FIT description: Linux 5.11.11
    Image 0 (kernel@0)
     Description:  Linux 5.11.11
     Type:         Kernel Image
     Compression:  gzip compressed
     Data Start:   0x801000c0
     Data Size:    5167511 Bytes = 4.9 MiB
     Architecture: MIPS
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x80100000
     Entry Point:  0x809898f4
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   b963ed48f45e332bd5df263dd69d69c3818e6586
    Image 1 (fdt@luton_pcb091)
     Description:  MSCC Luton PCB091 Device Tree
     Type:         Flat Device Tree
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x805edb60
     Data Size:    2851 Bytes = 2.8 KiB
     Architecture: MIPS
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   5283ae4322294e594a7be5e6de65e4f039ff36a5
    Default Configuration: 'conf@default'
    Configuration 0 (conf@default)
     Description:  Generic Linux kernel
     Kernel:       kernel@0
    Configuration 1 (pcb091)
     Description:  Luton Linux kernel
     Kernel:       kernel@0
     FDT:          fdt@luton_pcb091
## Checking hash(es) for FIT Image at 80100000 ...
   Hash(es) for Image 0 (kernel@0): sha1+ 
   Hash(es) for Image 1 (fdt@luton_pcb091): sha1+
```

However, when I attempt to boot the kernel, u-boot gives the following error:

```
luton # bootm 0x80100000
## Loading kernel from FIT Image at 80100000 ...
   Using 'conf@default' configuration
   Trying 'kernel@0' kernel subimage
     Description:  Linux 5.11.11
     Type:         Kernel Image
     Compression:  gzip compressed
     Data Start:   0x801000c0
     Data Size:    5167511 Bytes = 4.9 MiB
     Architecture: MIPS
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x80100000
     Entry Point:  0x809898f4
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   b963ed48f45e332bd5df263dd69d69c3818e6586
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
   Uncompressing Kernel Image
Error: inflate() returned -3
gzip compressed: uncompress error -1
Must RESET board to recover
```

The size of the kernel is well below the limit defined by [CONFIG_SYS_BOOTM_LEN](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/include/configs/vcoreiii.h#L47) (16MB) so I don't believe that is the root cause of this error.

The `vmlinux.bin.gz` used to generate the `itb` is a valid gzip archive and the decompressed size is also less than the `CONFIG_SYS_BOOTM_LEN` limit:

```
$ file vmlinux.bin.gz
vmlinux.bin.gz: gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 11494800
```

I have tried creating the `itb` file using the uncompressed `vmlinux.bin` (I simply edited `vmlinux.its` to have `data = /incbin/("vmlinux.bin");` and `compression = "none";` and the entry address indicated by `readelf -h vmlinux`) but I receive the following error when trying to boot:

```
luton # bootm ${loadaddr}
## Loading kernel from FIT Image at 80100000 ...
   Using 'conf@luton_pcb091' configuration
   Trying 'kernel@0' kernel subimage
     Description:  Linux 5.11.0
     Type:         Kernel Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x801000c0
     Data Size:    11584912 Bytes = 11 MiB
     Architecture: MIPS
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x80100000
     Entry Point:  0x809898f4
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   d13175476fd38269a02a3e85bef53419092c01e1
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
## Loading fdt from FIT Image at 80100000 ...
   Using 'conf@luton_pcb091' configuration
   Trying 'fdt@luton_pcb091' fdt subimage
     Description:  img,luton_pcb091 Device Tree
     Type:         Flat Device Tree
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x80c0c758
     Data Size:    2303 Bytes = 2.2 KiB
     Architecture: MIPS
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   daa8a8147bbce692d81383af7b748a763212bb24
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x80c0c758
   Loading Kernel Image
ERROR: new format image overwritten - must RESET the board to recover
```

Looking at `bootm_load_os` in `common/bootm.c` it appears that this error is telling me that there is some overlap between the kernel I'm trying to boot and... something, I'm not sure of what.

Here is `vmlinux.its` generated by kernel 5.11:

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 */
/dts-v1/;
/ {
 description = "Linux 5.11.11";
 #address-cells = <1>;
 images {
  kernel@0 {
   description = "Linux 5.11.11";
   data = /incbin/("vmlinux.bin.gz");
   type = "kernel";
   arch = "mips";
   os = "linux";
   compression = "gzip";
   load = /bits/ 32 <0xffffffff80100000>;
   entry = /bits/ 32 <0xffffffff809898f4>;
   hash@0 {
    algo = "sha1";
   };
  };
 };
 configurations {
  default = "conf@default";
  conf@default {
   description = "Generic Linux kernel";
   kernel = "kernel@0";
  };
 };
};
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: (GPL-2.0 OR MIT) */
/ {
 images {
  fdt@luton_pcb091 {
   description = "MSCC Luton PCB091 Device Tree";
   data = /incbin/("boot/dts/mscc/luton_pcb091.dtb");
   type = "flat_dt";
   arch = "mips";
   compression = "none";
   hash@0 {
    algo = "sha1";
   };
  };
 };
 configurations {
  pcb091 {
   description = "Luton Linux kernel";
   kernel = "kernel@0";
   fdt = "fdt@luton_pcb091";
  };
 };
};
```

`binwalk` doesn't indicate that the `gzip` data in the ITB is invalid:

```
$ binwalk vmlinux.gz.itb 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             device tree image (dtb)
192           0xC0            gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)
3960903       0x3C7047        MySQL ISAM compressed data file Version 10
5167968       0x4EDB60        device tree image (dtb)
```

`mkimage version 2020.01` is built by buildroot as part of `host-uboot-tools-2020.01`

---

As per the suggestion from Tom Rini, I changed the loadaddr of the FIT image and no longer receive the `uncompress` error, however the system still does not appear to boot. I've moved this to a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990613/u-boot-hangs-at-uncompressing-loading-kernel-image).

Comment: How much memory does the platform have?  Can you include the full log from power  on?

Comment: 128MB, the u-boot serial output up until dhcp/tftp is here: https://gist.github.com/halmartin/5aeb62c8698860784e5d96ab81e68949

Comment: The board device tree is based on the luton_pcb090 which is in upstream u-boot. The only modifications I've made are removing mdio1 (the switch only has 10 ports) and renaming it to MS220-8P.

Comment: inflate() has returned Z_DATA_ERROR (-3): the input data was corrupted (input stream not conforming to the zlib format or incorrect check value). Please, provide the *.itb file and the mkimage command that you used to create the FIT image. Please, also indicate the version of U-Boot and mkimage.

Comment: @Xypron I updated the question with the requested information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final problem you run in to:

> ERROR: new format image overwritten - must RESET the board to recover

is because you've loaded the image in to memory in the same location as the entry point but you need to load it in to memory somewhere else so that U-Boot can unpack the image and put the contents where their load address is set to.  Since you have 128MB of memory you should be able to put it at +32 or +64MB from start and then things should work.

Comment: So u-boot will still relocate the image to the entry point even when uncompressed?

Comment: Not sure on MIPS but on x86 the image is loaded to separate space and copied so that unneeded sections can be skipped. Then the loaded image space is freed.

Comment: It is possible to make an execute-in-place image where you load the kernel image to exactly the right spot in memory, but to do that you use a different image type and also note that in your example above it ends up at 0x801000c0 and not 0x80100000 (so you would need to have offset the load of the fit image in memory a bit more.  To be clear, in both error cases you show, the problem stems from placing the image in memory too close to where it needs to be to execute and you need to use a safe address that's outside of where the image needs to end up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Tom. As per my latest edit, I'm still unable to boot the kernel as it appears to hang on "Uncompressing/Loading Kernel Image" but this is probably unrelated to the original overlapping memory issue. Your answer resolves the original issue, so I will mark it as correct.